# Identify a light green columnar cactus

Tags: identification, cactus

I bought a Cactus from the local garden center. Unfortunately the guy that I bought the plants from was a novice so he didn't know the plant's name.

Can you tell me its name plus some advice about taking care of it?

[image]

Comment: We have a site policy of one plant per [tag:identification] question; see https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/826/for-identification-please-only-post-one-plant-per-question-and-be-specific-whe. I've edited your post to comply; please post separate questions for the other two.

Answer (score 1):

Could be *Cleistocactus winterii* or "Monkey tail" cactus.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure?! Monkey Tails are fluffy and stuff but mine is not. I mean just look at the picture you posted!